# Converting a linear space into a orthonormal base

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I've been given a linear space made by 2 equations $U = \{\ {(x,y,z,w) ∈ R^4: x - y + z = 0 \land y - z + w = 0} \}\ $

and I have to get the orthonormal base of this equation and what I did to to that is I turned it into this matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1&0\\
    0&1&-1&1
   \\
    \end{pmatrix}$
and what I did was the null space of this matrix and with its vectors I divided each vector for its magnitude giving me in the end $\begin{pmatrix}0\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
    0
   \\
    \end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
0\\
   \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
   \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

but the answer is $(-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{5},-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10},\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10},-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{5})$ so what did I do wrong?

Comment: There are an infinite number of orthonormal bases for any linear space of dimension greater than $1$.

Comment: Something does not add up here. This is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that has dimension 4. We have two restrictions (so we are left with only two degrees of freedom; two free variables )  so we expect the subspace to be of dimension 2. The answer you provide has only one vector which cannot span the linear subspace. Any way, I would find a basis then apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Comment: The second vector you have got as part of orthonormal base is incorrect. It is not orthogonal to the first row of your matrix. But the fact stated by @Medo is still valid and the space should be $2-$D. In fact, the answer given in your textbook is also incorrect as it is not orthogonal to the second row of your matrix.